# Prevent opening fold under the cursor when moving the cursor to left or right in Vim

Tags: vim, move, fold

Whenever I move the cursor left or right using h or l, the fold under the cursor opens automatically. By the way, moving top or down does not have this problem. Is there any way to prevent automatically opening fold when moving horizontally?

Comment: See `:help 'foldopen'`.

Answer (score 4):

You can create the auto command:

```
autocmd! CursorMoved * if foldclosed('.') != -1 |
                     \   nnoremap h <nop>|
                     \   nnoremap l <nop>|
                     \ else |
                     \   silent! unmap h|
                     \   silent! unmap l|
                     \ endif
```

Here `foldclosed('.')` returns `-1` if current line is unfolded. Instead of using this auto command just avoid pressing `h` or `l` over folds.

Answer (score 2):

The default value of [`:help 'foldopen'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#'foldopen') has `hor` in it; this causes horizontal movements (like `l`, `h`) to open folds.

To disable this, simply add this to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set foldopen-=hor
```